# GitHub Student Benefits After Graduation

Tags: github

I am currently enrolled as a university student and I would like to benefit from PRO versions of GitHub. I can do it using my documentation but I want to know what happens to my account after I graduate. I searched it online but I couldn't find enough useful information. Some people say that nothing happens you can just downgrade but others say that your account is locked forever and your all private repositories become public. So has anyone experienced such a thing after graduation?